# Stripe Error - Your card's expiration year is invalid

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

Testing my stripe js account on test mode. I'm running this piece of code

```
Stripe.card.createToken({
  number: "4242424242424242",  
  cvc: "333", 
  exp_month: "02", 
  exp_year: "19", 
  address_zip: "11111", 
  address_country: "AX"}, 
stripeResponseHandler);
```

And I keep receiving this response error.

```
Your card's expiration year is invalid.
```

Even if I change the year to `2019`, I still receive the error. I double checked and am using the correct test key. What's wrong and how do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried other years? 2017? (I've never had a credit card with an expiry date more than three years in the future.)

Comment: `12/2016` gives me the same error. This has me stumped.

Comment: Have you looked at the logs in the dashboard to make sure that you're sending exactly what you think your code is sending? I'm guessing that maybe you keep sending `19` or `16` in `exp_year` and it requires a 4-digits year

Comment: This is surprising. I've set a simple JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/00Lnfdx3/. As you can see, I'm making the same `Stripe.card.createToken()` call as you are, and a token is successfully returned.

Comment: Am am now having the exact same issue (after 3 years :) ). @jason328 have you figured it out?

Comment: @gion_13, Unfortunately no. Sorry gion :(

Comment: I bumped into this issue once I separated stripe elements. Having one Card element would not face this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because `EndYear` is a number, not a string.

Check this out: https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_card?lang=dotnet

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Stripe document](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/v2#card-createToken), `exp_month` and `exp_year` need to be number.

> exp_month: two digit number representing the card's expiration month
>   (e.g., 12)
>
> exp_year: two or four digit number representing the card's expiration year 
>       (e.g., 2021)

```js
Stripe.card.createToken({
  number: "4242424242424242",  
  cvc: "333", 
  exp_month: 02, 
  exp_year: 2022, 
  address_zip: "11111", 
  address_country: "AX"}, 
stripeResponseHandler);
```

Or [you can set expiration in type of string too](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/v2#passing-exp-dates).

```js
Stripe.card.validateExpiry('09 2022')  // true
Stripe.card.validateExpiry('2024/09')  // true
Stripe.card.validateExpiry('2024/09')  // true
Stripe.card.validateExpiry('2024-09')  // true
```

And the time need to be in the future

Answer (score -1):

case 1 :  `exp_year` >= `current_year` ✅ gives => tok_1OYsG82eZvKYlo2CTNnJ5N0f

case 2 : `exp_year` < `current_year` ❌ gives => Your card's expiration year is invalid.

if you enter past years (value less than current year)
then it will gives you this error

Comment: OP's question was in 2015, though. 2019 was valid at the time.